# Can I combine values from multiple rows in another table into multiple columns of one row using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables:
T1:

```
| M_ID | P_ID1 | P_ID2 | rest of T1 columns |
|  0   |   0   |   1   |         ...        |
|  1   |   2   |   3   |         ...        |
```

T2:

```
| P_ID | Type | A | B |
|  0   |   1  | a | e |
|  1   |   2  | b | f |
|  2   |   1  | c | g |
|  3   |   2  | d | h |
```

Now, I want to have a query that selects this:

```
| M_ID | P_1a | P_1b | P_2a | P_2b | rest of T1 columns |
|  0   |  a   |  e   |  b   |  f   |         ...        |
|  1   |  c   |  g   |  c   |  h   |         ...        |
```

So, in words: I want to select all columns from T1, but I want to replace P_ID1 with the columns from T2, where the P_ID is equal to P_ID1, and the type is 1, and basically the same for P_ID2.

I can obviously get the information I need with multiple queries, but I was wondering if there is a way that I can do this with one query. Any ideas?

I'm currently using SQL Server 2008r2, but I'd also be interested in solutions for other database software.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you just need to use a join:

```
select T1.M_ID, t2_1.A as P_1a, t2_1.B as P_1b, t2_2.A as P_2a, t2_2.B as P_2b, ...
from T1, T2 t2_1, T2 t2_2
where T1.P_ID1 = t2_1.P_ID and T1.P_ID2 = t2_2.P_ID
```

basically we are joining T1 onto T2 twice, once for the P_1 values and a second time for the P_2 values. You need to alias T2 when you join it twice to distinguish between the two (that's what the t2_1 and t2_2 are - a means of distinguishing between the two instances of the joined T2).

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as @John Pickup's solution only using modern join syntax:

```
select T1.M_ID, t2_1.A as P_1a, t2_1.B as P_1b, t2_2.A as P_2a, t2_2.B as P_2b, ...
from T1
     join T2 t2_1 on T1.P_ID1 = t2_1.P_ID 
     join T2 t2_2 on T1.P_ID2 = t2_2.P_ID
```

I only post a seperate answer, as there is no code formatting in comments [as you get told here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/to-put-syntax-highligthing-on-for-codes-in-comments)